# R dplyr::mutate with ifelse conditioned on a global variable recycles result from first row

Tags: r, conditional-statements, vectorization, dplyr

I am curious why an `ifelse()` statement within a call to `dplyr::mutate()` only seems to apply to the first row of my data frame. This returns a single value, which is recycled down the entire column. Since the expressions evaluated in either case of the `ifelse()` are only valid in the context of my data frame, I would expect the condition check and resulting expression evaluations to be performed on the columns as a whole, not just their first elements.

Here's an example: I have a variable defined outside the data frame called `checkVar`. Depending on the value of `checkVar`, I want to add differnt values to my data frame in a new column, `z`, that are computed as a function of existing columns.

If I do

```
checkVar <- 1
df <- data.frame( x=11:15, y=1:5 ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( z=ifelse(checkVar == 1, x/y, x-y) )
df
```

it returns

```
   x y  z
1 11 1 11
2 12 2 11
3 13 3 11
4 14 4 11
5 15 5 11
```

Instead of z being the quotient of x and y for each row, all rows are populated with the quotient of x and y from the first row of the data frame.

However, if I specify `rowwise()`, I get the result I want:

```
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate( z=ifelse(checkVar == 1, x/y, x-y) ) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
df
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      x     y         z
  <int> <int>     <dbl>
1    11     1 11.000000
2    12     2  6.000000
3    13     3  4.333333
4    14     4  3.500000
5    15     5  3.000000
```

Why do I have to explicitly specify `rowwise()` when `x` and `y` are only defined as columns of my data frame?

Comment: `checkVar` is of `length` 1. This, I believe, leads to only the first row of `x` and `y` being used. If you set `checkVar <- rep(1,5)`, you get your desired output. If you used `dplyr`'s `if_else`, it would tell you what the issue is. Also, using `rowwise` makes it so that everything inside the `ifelse` is of length 1.

Comment: If you use dplyr version of `ifelse`, which is `if_else`, then you got error `"true is length 5 not 1 or 1."`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not really related to `dplyr::mutate` but to how `ifelse` works, here is the docs *?ifelse*:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.
>
> Usage
>
> ifelse(test, yes, no)

And example:

```
ifelse(T, c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))
# [1] 1
```

Your first case is vectorized, `ifelse` takes vectors `x/y` and `x-y` as `yes` and `no` parameters, since `checkVar == 1` returns *TRUE* (scalar), `ifelse` returns `(x/y)[1]`, i.e. the first element of vector `x/y`, which is *11* and get recycled to fill the new column `z`;

In your second case, `mutate` and `ifelse` is executed per row, so it's evaluated *five* times, and each time returns the value of `x/y` for that row.

---

If your condition is scalar, then you don't need *vectorized* `ifelse`, `if/else` is more suitable to use:

```
checkVar <- 1
mutate(df, z = if(checkVar == 1) x/y else x-y)

#   x y         z
#1 11 1 11.000000
#2 12 2  6.000000
#3 13 3  4.333333
#4 14 4  3.500000
#5 15 5  3.000000
```

Comment: Your last example is very interesting; I didn't even know you could use the standard `if/else` construct on the right-hand side of an assignment within a call to `mutate`. Thanks for posting; this is very good to know!

Comment: Alternative: `mutate(z = case_when(checkVar==1 ~ x/y, TRUE ~ as.numeric(x-y)))`

Comment: @bmosov01 Glad it helps!

Comment: @Marek `case_when` will still errors out here. The longest LHS in the formulas should have the same length of the longest RHS in `case_when` to work correctly.

Comment: @Psidom Strange, works for me dplyr-0.7.3 on R-3.4.2

Comment: @Marek You're right. It works after upgraded `dplyr`.